# yii2 formwizard checkbox field and customize preview step

Tags: yii2, yii2-formwizard

I am using [yii2-formwizard](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard) and I want to insert a checkbox as form input field for the field `is_legal` in a tabular step.
So in `fieldConfig` array, reading the documentation, I inserted the following code:

```
'is_legal' => [
    'options' => [
        'type' => 'checkbox',
    ],
    'labelOptions' => [
        'label' => \Yii::t('app', 'Legal Representative'),
    ],
],
```

The following image shows the result:

[image: Result]

However, when I go the preview step I see the field of the checkbox set as undefined: 
[image: Step preview]

In fact, when I try to save the model, the `is_legal` field is not set.

**First Question**: where is the problem with the checkbox form field?

**Second Question**: is there any way to customize the preview step? For example instead of 'Step 5', I would like to write 'Legal Data'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created this widget and there are a few things you need to know.

#### First Answer

- The `undefined` it is showing is not the `value` but the `label` of the checkbox, if you look into the [`getLabel()`](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard/blob/master/src/assets/js/formwizard.js#L219) function in the `formwizard.js` file it looks into the siblings of the `input` field for a `label` and gets its text

  ```
  let text = $('#' + fieldName).siblings('label').text();
  ```

  to display on the preview step, and by default Yii2 wraps the input inside the `label` like

  ```
  <label><input stype="checkbox"></label>
  ```

  so you need to use the `template` option of the checkbox like below

  ```php
  'is_legal' => [
      'options' => [
          'type' => 'checkbox',
          'template' => '{input}{beginLabel}{labelTitle}{endLabel}{error}{hint}',
      ],
      'labelOptions' => [
          'label' => \Yii::t('app', 'Legal Representative'),
      ],
  ],
  ```

#### Second Answer

- No, currently the widget does not support the custom title for the Preview step sections, but i think I can add the support for providing the title of the headings as it makes sense too, if that sorts your problem.

#### Update

Ignore the **Second Answer** given above i just pushed the updates to the live branch you can now use the `previewHeading` option in the step settings. Update your composer by running `composer update` to update to the latest version and clear cache using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

See the following sample code how to use `previewHeading` option

```
use buttflattery\formwizard\FormWizard;

echo FormWizard::widget([
    'enablePreview'=>true,
    'steps'=>[
        [
            'model'=>$user,
            'title'=>'My Shoots',
            'previewHeading'=>'My Heading Step 1',
            'description'=>'Add your shoots',
            'formInfoText'=>'Fill all fields'
        ],
        [
            'model'=> $profile,
            'title'=>'My Shoots',
            'previewHeading'=>'My Heading Step 2',
            'description'=>'Add your shoots',
            'formInfoText'=>'Fill all fields'
        ],
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! However now I have other issues related to the two question:

**First Question**: I have noticed that when I unselect the checkbox the value of `is_legal` field is always 1 as described by the [image](https://imgur.com/a/52DoCyg)


**Second Question**: I have updated the widget at the last version, running `composer update`. However I don't see any change as shown on the first question image. [Step code](https://imgur.com/a/wV37uwQ)

Comment: @johnnymondo you should remove everything from the `app/web/assets` folder and clear cache to load the latest files, i have tested it before pushing it to live, you might have the old javascript assets loaded in the page that is the reason, and i will check on the other thing related to the **value showing 1 for the `is_legal` even if not selected** once i reach home, you can create a separate question and add a reference to this post in that new question and i will look into and reply asap, you can mark this answer if the initial problem you mentioned in your question is solved.

Comment: I haven't removed the app/web/asset folder. Now the preview step is ok. For the checkbox issue I have created the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207215/yii2-formwizard-checkbox-field-value-set-to-1-even-if-not-selected).