# yii2 formwizard checkbox field value set to 1 even if not selected

Tags: yii2, yii2-formwizard

I am using `yii2-formwizard` and I want to insert a `checkbox` as form input field for the field `is_legal` in a tabular step. So in `fieldConfig` array, reading the documentation, I inserted the following code:

```
'is_legal' => [
    'options' => [
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'template' => '{input}{beginLabel}{labelTitle}{endLabel}{error}{hint}',
    ],
    'labelOptions' => ['label' => \Yii::t('app', 'Legal Representative')],
],
```

If I select the checkbox or not the value of the field is always `1` as shown on: [image: Preview step].

However, when I add another instance of the model, in the preview step I have  `NA` as value of the `legal representative` field :

[image: Preview step2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct about it. It incorrectly shows the value even if the check box is not checked i have updated the section and added a [fix](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard/commit/f002666e7cebc2ce348b979fdac80e391dc6922e).

```
//check if single checkbox input

if (inputType.attr("type") == 'checkbox') {
    return inputType.is(":checked") ? inputType.val() : '';
}
```

To get the latest code you need to repeat the steps for running composer using,

```
composer update
```

and clear the browser cache along with clearing the `assets` folder in the `web` directory.

Normally when i am working locally with extensions or if there is an update for an extension which includes javascript updates i add the following settings under the `components` array in my local config file that takes care of getting the latest files from, and the assets are force copied every time to the `web/assets/` directory whenever you refresh the browser or the page reloads.

```
'components'=>[
    'assetManager' => [
        'forceCopy' => true,
    ],
]
```

*Note: Dont leave it open on live site as it would make the page load slower.*

Comment: Thank you for updating the repository! Now it seems to work, but since the step is tabular and after setting the `is_legal` field, when I add another `Associate` the new checkbox is checked. To resolve the problem I add the following code to `is_legal` [field config](https://justpaste.it/1o2k7). The result is that the checkbox is unchecked but when I set it, its value is `NA`.

Comment: @johnnymondo i am in office at the moment will look into it tonight when i reach home and will push a fix if there is any issue with the code base, i didnt knew you were trying this with tabular step, so i might have to test it locally first, or if it is related to your code you are using, will suggest the fix for your code.

Comment: ok no problem. I'm actually checking my code. If I will find a solution, I will post here. Thanks again for your help.